# What's the use of contracts if wrestlers are allowed to leave anytime they want?

Tags: wwe, wcw

Chris Benoit wrestled for WCW at Souled Out (2000), then left for the WWF shortly after he won the championship. Here Benoit left WCW with the championship still on him.

What's the use of contracts in professional wrestling TV shows if wrestlers are allowed to leave anytime they want?

Comment: I'm afraid this might fall on the [off-topic side of the wrestling spectrum](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1449/49).

Comment: I have a contract with my employer, but it doesn't stop me leaving.

Comment: Why do so many NFL players sit out until their contract is renegotiated?  Why are so many MLB players sitting out this year?  I don't know all the legal ramifications of sports contracts, but it seems they're not very legally binding, or they have massive loopholes that benefit the athlete.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it relates more to a legal questions than to the TV side of professional wrestling.  Wrestling is tenuously on topic as it is (sports is off topic, but wrestling is arguably closer to reality TV).

Comment: This might be on topic at Law SE; not sure. But it doesn't sound like the question is specific to professional wresting; couldn't you ask the same about any contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the use of contracts in professional wrestling TV shows if wrestlers are allowed to leave anytime they want?

You seem to be actually asking a different question which is why was he "allowed" to leave while holding the Championship title.

Firstly, a contract is just that, an agreement with legal penalties written in. No one is "forced" to work.

The wrestler is free to leave at any time BUT there may (and usually are) legal requirements he MUST observe if he does. They usually involve (but are not limited to) non-compete clauses, financial penalties and hush clauses etc.

As to your implied question:

We do not know the terms of Benoit's contract or the details of his leaving WCW but it's clear WCW *expected* him to renew his contract (or they would not have hung the title on him) but couldn't come to terms with him and so he left.

> Benoit was unhappy working for WCW. One last attempt in January 2000 was made to try to keep him with WCW, by putting the vacant WCW World Heavyweight Championship on him by defeating Sid Vicious at Souled Out. However, due to disagreements with management and to protest the promotion of Kevin Sullivan to head booker, Benoit left the company the next day alongside his friends Eddie Guerrero, Dean Malenko, and Perry Saturn, forfeiting his title in the process.
>
> *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Benoit#The_Revolution_and_World_Heavyweight_Champion_(1999%E2%80%932000))*